# Gmail blocks links in "Reset Stack Overflow password" email

Tags: discussion, bug, login, accounts

Recently I had the frustrating experience with resetting my password for Stack Overflow, apparently in the Gmail mobile web and mobile application. The email sent with the link to reset password is marked as

> This message seems dangerous

It would prevent me from clicking any of the reset links in the email, which I might add was mildly frustrating. I had to use the *older version* of Gmail in order reset my password.

Is there a reason why Gmail flagged this as dangerous? I usually use a lot of services and the reset emails aren't usually flagged.

Comment: Does the mail contain some css with `display: none`?

Comment: I was checking it on mobile, I'll check it on Desktop to see those settings.

but I think the `display: none` was not there because I could see the links along with highlighting. Only the hyperlinks were removed from the email.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Links in E-Mails look like phishing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327397/158100)